# how to get capture all arguments of mock

Tags: spock

I got mock:

```
MyService myServiceMock=Mock()
```

In my test I'm using it like this:

```
myCollection.stream()
    .map(myServiceMock::myMethod)
    ...
```

How I can get all arguments passed to `myServiceMock` in all invocations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface MyService {
    def myMethod(String s)
}

def foo() {
    given:
        def capturedArguments = []
        MyService myServiceMock = Mock {
            myMethod(_) >> { capturedArguments << it.first() }
        }
        def myCollection = ['a', 'b']

    when:
        myCollection
                .stream()
                .map(myServiceMock::myMethod)
                .each { }

    then:
        capturedArguments ==~ ['a', 'b']
}
```